# Android apps - when was APK signing introduced as Google Play Store submission requirement?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, code-signing

Has Google Play / Android Marketplace always required APKs to be signed to be submitted?  If not, does anyone know when this was first introduced?

Comment: I started uploading apps in mid 2014.  I had to have my app signed.  So it's been that way for a while.  And so be it.  Because it's a good practice.  Protects everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has Google Play / Android Marketplace always required APKs to be signed to be submitted?

Yes. More accurately, APKs must be signed to be installed on devices.